# Pull multiple values from a string using RegEx

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the string `"{:name=>\"entry 1\", :description=>\"description 1\"}"`

I'm using regex to get the values of name and description...

```
string = "{:name=>\"entry 1\", :description=>\"description 1\"}"

name = /\:name=>\"(.*?)\,/.match(string)
description = /\:description=>\"(.*?)\,/.match(string)
```

This however only returns `name` as `#<MatchData ":name=>\"entry 1\"," 1:"entry 1\"">` and `description` comes back as `nil`.

What I ideally want is for `name` to return `"entry 1"` and `description` come back as `"description 1"`

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong... any ideas?

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: Ruby and Ruby on Rails

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but note: `eval(string).values #=> ["entry 1", "description 1"] `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the comma in `/\:description=>\"(.*?)\,/` should be `/\:description=>\"(.*?)/` or `/\:description=>\"([^"]+)/`

Also you can this method:

```
def extract_value_from_string(string, key)
  %r{#{key}=>\"([^"]+)}.match(string)[1]
end

extract_value_from_string(string, 'description')
=> "description 1"
extract_value_from_string(string, 'name')
=> "name 1"
```

Comment: Thank you.... I ended up just using `/\:description=>\"([^"]+)/.match(string)` and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this regex to retrieve both `name` and `description` at one step

```
(?<=name=>\\"|description=>\\")[^\\]+
```

try this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kH4cJ1/1)

I know this demo is using `PCRE` but I've tested also on `http://rubular.com/` and it works fine

and if you want to get them separately use this regex is to extract name `(?<=name=>\\")[^\\]+` and this for description `(?<=description=>\\")[^\\]+`

Comment: Not sure why but it works in Rubular but in my controller when I try `p description = /(?<=description=>\\")[^\\]+/.match(string)` it returns `nil`